# getSupportedPreviewSizes() returning multiple picture sizes for multiple devices. How can i specify single size which supports all devices

Tags: android, camera

I have Moto Z play returning 14 sizes after getSupportedPreviewSizes() and I have samsung galaxy ace returning only 3 sizes.

I want to specify a medium preview size which supports all the devices. How can i achive that?

Example if i specify PictureSize = "5"

List sizeList = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

param.setPictureSize(sizeList.get(5).width, sizeList.get(5).height);

so if kept 5 then this code will work on Z play but it will crash on samsung galaxy ace.

Comment: Use param.setPictureSize(sizeList.get(sizeList.size()/2).width, sizeList.get(sizeList.size()/2).height);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the best preview size based on screen size of mobile device

Refer this https://gist.github.com/Arjun-sna/58251a60d86239f196e735447a97dab2